# How to find all numbers containing a specific digit in a range of numbers from 1 to 100?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list of items from 1 to 100 inside 1 list.

Query 1:

Suppose if I want to find 6 from 1 to 100, the new list 
should have - `6,16,26,36,46,56,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,76,86,96`.
How do we achieve this?

Query 2:

The specific number can be anything of our choice like if I have 4
then the new list should be - `4,14,24,34,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,54,64,74,84,94`.

So can we have a generic logic for both or we need to have different logic for any specific numbers?

**EDIT**

This is what I have tried so far,

```
z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
for i in z: 
    if i == 6: 
        print(i)
```

I was only able to get it from for 1 to 10 but could not get it for 1 to 100.

Comment: `[i for i in arr if i % 10 == n]` seems to fit your desired results.  But what about all numbers in the 60s or 40s? Those contain the number as well.

Comment: Should `14` be in the second results?  This looks like just `range(x, 100, 10)`

Comment: yes 14 should be there .. i missed it to add

Comment: >>> z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
         
>>> for i in z:
        if i == 6:
            print(i)

         
6
>>>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the program,

```
x = list(range(1, 101)) 
n = str(input("Enter a number: "))
output = [i for i in x if n in str(i)]
print (output)
```

Output:

> Enter a number: `4`
>
> Output: `[4, 14, 24, 34, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 54, 64, 74, 84, 94]`

where the number of your choice `n` is `4`.

> Enter a number: `6`
>
> Output: `[6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 76, 86, 96]`

where the number of your choice `n` is `6`.

> `x = list(range(1, 101))`

- The `range()` function can be used to create long lists. The `list()` function then uses numbers from this sequence to create a list.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can get all numbers from your range using modulo (`%`) and integer division (`//`):

```
x = range(1,101)
b = [i for i in x if i % 10 == 6 or i // 10 == 6]
print(b)
```

The modulu part will get you any value that has a 6 in your "ones" - the integer division gets all values that have a 6 at the "tens" place:

```
[6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 76, 86, 96]
```

Answer (score 0):

I now have it figured out:

```
[i for i in x if i % 10 == 6]          
# [6, 16]


[i for i in x if i % 10 == 4]
# [4, 14]
```

Comment: Is it only *ends with* the desired number? What about all numbers in the 40s and 60s?

Comment: yes now i see those numbers are not there.. i just validated with upto 20 numbers ...

Comment: If you need those, then try something like `[i for i in x if '4' in str(i)]` (make sure your `n` is also a string)

Comment: [i for i in y if '4' in str(i)]
         
[4, 14, 24, 34, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 54, 64, 74, 84, 94]

Answer (score 0):

```
# For k = 0
k = 0
print([i for i in range(k,101,10)])   #Only for zero

# For k > 0  and GENERIC
k = 6
print([i for i in range(k,101,10)])
# doesn't include 60-69
#### Output  ####
#[6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66, 76, 86, 96]


print([i for i in range(k,101,10)] + [i for i in range(k*10,(k+1)*10)])
# this includes all 6 poosible in the range 1-100
#### Output  ####
#[6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66, 76, 86, 96,60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]


list_of_fours = [i for i in range(4,101,10)] + [i for i in range(4*10,(4+1)*10)]
list_of_six = [i for i in range(6,101,10)] + [i for i in range(6*10,(6+1)*10)]
print(list_of_fours+list_of_six)
#if only concern is 4 and 6
#### Output  ####
# list_of_fours = [4, 14, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 74, 84, 94, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
# list_of_fours = [6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66, 76, 86, 96, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]
#[4, 14, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 74, 84, 94, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66, 76, 86, 96]
```

Comment: The question was ill defined - he was looking for numbers that contain `4 or 6` in either digit. you are missing 40-49 / 60-69 (not my downvote) - also : 1 question you present 3 different answers ...

Comment: I have modified the code as well. And i'm just showing possible ways of doing it and which can be used based on the specific requirements.